# How to copy contents of one array to another using pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I have three Pointers:

```
int *x,*y, *Temp;
```

And then I have done

```
x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
Temp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(m+n));
```

where m and n are certain values.

Next, I have entered values into Temp.

```
  for(i=0; i < m+n; i++) {
  scanf("%d", Temp+i);
  }
```

I want half of Temp in x and the other half in y. How do I do this?

```
for(i=0; i < m; i++) {
  x[i] = Temp[i];
}
```

The code above to copy the contents is not working!

Also, how do I print the values?

Comment: Usual disclaimer: [In C you should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (or any function returning `void *`).

Comment: As for your problem, can you please be more specific? Just saying "this is not working" doesn't really tell us much, *how* is it not working? Do you get build errors? Run-time errors? Unexpected results? Something else? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Why did you add `2` to the size of `Temp`?

Comment: It is compiling and running but getting a garbage value in the place.

Comment: you may use `calloc` which initializes the allocated memory or use `memset` to set the memory locations to NULL.

Comment: The small parts  of code you show doesn't tell us the whole story, and the parts you show if put together in a single `main` function should work just fine (for reasonable values of `m` and `n`, and if `<stdlib.h>` has been included). You really need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: The code you have posted so far is correct, please post a MCVE showing the problem.  Also, instead of "is not working", say: (a) what happened, (b) what you expected.

Answer (score 6):

Using `memcpy` is probably the easiest way to accomplish what you want:

```
memcpy(x, Temp, m * sizeof*Temp);
memcpy(y, &Temp[m], n * sizeof*Temp);
```

To print the values, just use `printf`:

```
puts("Values in x:");
for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      printf("%d\n", x[i]); 
}

puts("Values in y:");
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      printf("%d\n", y[i]);
}
```

Comment: So in this, first m values are copied to X from Temp. Then I need to increment 1 place and assign the rest (everything but the last) to y. how do i go about that?

Comment: @Vidya Just use the example that I gave

Comment: @PCLuddite Please see it once running . I think it throws garbage .

Comment: memcpy() is copying only half the array correctly. The other half is 0s.

Comment: @M.M That was residual from an edit. It originally said "using `memcpy` and `printf` in a loop". I moved `printf` to a different section, but neglected to remove the "in a loop" part. I fixed the answer.

Comment: @ameyCU @Vidya I didn't multiply the number of bytes by `sizeof*Temp` (this is what I get for not testing it first). The code works now.

Answer (score 3):

[Use `memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).It will copy desired numbre of bytes .

[What I was doing is already mentioned in this answer of PC Luddite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094774/how-to-copy-contents-of-one-array-to-another-using-pointers-in-c/33094881#33094881)

Comment: for memcpy(), how many bytes should I consider? I need to put half the value in x and the other half in y

Answer (score 3):

You can use as follows to print the values. I just use `M` in place of `m` for better clarity.

```
for(i=0; i < M; i++) {
printf("VAL: %d\n",x[i]);
}
```

Similarly you can also print another array `y`.

Comment: Its look clearer to me for sure. Beauty lies on the eyes of beholder after all.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really look like you need to allocate all that memory, nor does it seem like you need to copy it. Consider using this alternative approach:

```
int* xy = malloc(sizeof(*xy) * (m+n));
int* x = xy;
int* y = xy + n;
...
free(xy);
```